# How to change Binding property column name of jtable?

Tags: java, swing, binding, jtable

This is my first time using java binding so I created this method to help me.

```
public static final void BindTableToFields(JTable Table, Object[] Fields) {
    for (Object Field : Fields) {
        if (Field instanceof JTextField) {
            JTextField jTextField = (JTextField) Field;
            BeanProperty<JTable, Object> tableBeanProperty;
            BeanProperty<JTextField, String> textFieldProperty;
            Binding<JTable, Object, JTextField, String> binding;

            tableBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("selectedElement." + jTextField.getText());
            textFieldProperty = BeanProperty.create("text");
            binding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, Table, tableBeanProperty, jTextField, textFieldProperty);
            binding.bind();
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Now when I go to my designed frame and I set my JTextField text property to 'column1' the binding successfully works.

I tried to rename all my JTable columns names using this snippet of code.

```
public static ResultSet FillTableDataFromQuery(String Query, JTable table) throws SQLException {

    ResultSet rs = SQLTools.ExecuteQuery(Query);
    DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

    // Filling table model with data from database
    // ... (cutting irrelevant code)

    table.setModel(defaultTableModel);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {   
        table.getColumn(table.getColumnName(i)).setIdentifier(heads[i]);
    }
    return rs;
}
```

I'm filling data of the JTable then I use the binding method.

```
public final void InitFrame() throws SQLException {
    jtable1RS = FillTableDataFromQuery("SELECT * FROM users ;", jTable1);
    JTableSQLTool.HideColumns(jTable1, new int[] { 0, 1, 3 });
    JTableSQLTool.BindTableToFields(jTable1, new Object[] { JTF_ID, JTF_PAss, JTF_Profile, JTF_User });
}
```

This picture below illustrates my results.

[image: binding works successfully]

Now for my problem, is there a way to change the table column property name from `selectedElement.column1` to `selectedElement.ID`? This will make my design more significant.

I tried to use this code in the second method to rename `column1` to `ID` but it does not work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    table.getColumn(table.getColumnName(i)).setIdentifier(heads[i]);
}
```

Comment: heads is an array containing all my desired column property new text

Comment: after a day of reverse engeneering i discovered that each selected row on a jtable is a hashmap wich the binding converter will receive
this hashmap is structured as column[i]-->value[i] for each element and i think that why we tape {selectedElement.column[i]} . 
now is there a way to access this hash map and alter it structure ?? at table creation phase ?

Comment: It isn't very clear what the problem is. Are you trying to change the text in the table header? When you select a row the data goes to the textfields? Are the textfields supposed to edit the selected data in the table? What doesn't work? Also it is a little difficult to read, I would recommend following [camel case](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) when naming variables, methods, and classes.

Comment: dear @Matthew i m sorry for my bad english. selectedElement." + jTextField.getText() at runtime will be : selectedElement.column0 wich is the binding property for the first collumn in the table I want to rename this property for the first column to something more significant like : selectedElement.ID is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with how you are binding things but here is a small example I wrote. I hope that I understood what you are trying to do. You will want to look at my `bindFieldToTableColumn` method the most. When you edit a table cell, the JTextField value will change and visa versa. When you change the selected row in the table, the JTextFields will update their values and change based on the current row. You will also want to look at `changeColumnName` as I think that is what you are trying to do with your column headers. It will change the text above the column you choose. Tell me if this is what you were trying to do.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Testing {

    public static JTable table;
    public static JButton button;
    public static JTextField field1, field2, field3, field4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {}

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"}, 0);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Testing");
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane();
        frame.add(split, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        split.setLeftComponent(new JScrollPane(table));

        JPanel menu = new JPanel();
        menu.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        split.setRightComponent(menu);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        field1 = new JTextField();
        field1.setEnabled(false);
        bindFieldToTableColumn(field1, table, 0);

        field2 = new JTextField();
        field2.setEnabled(false);
        bindFieldToTableColumn(field2, table, 1);

        field3 = new JTextField();
        field3.setEnabled(false);
        bindFieldToTableColumn(field3, table, 2);

        field4 = new JTextField();
        field4.setEnabled(false);
        bindFieldToTableColumn(field4, table, 3);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        Insets margin = new Insets(2, 4, 2, 4);
        gbc.insets = margin;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        menu.add(button, gbc); 

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        menu.add(field1, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 2;
        menu.add(field2, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 3;
        menu.add(field3, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 4;
        menu.add(field4, gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        menu.add(new JPanel(), gbc);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Populate table to demonstrate.
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{r.nextInt(99999-10000)+10000,"username"+r.nextInt(100), (char)r.nextInt(255), (char)r.nextInt(255)});
        }

        // To change column header text you would do this.
        changeColumnName(table, 0, "ID");
        changeColumnName(table, 1, "Username");
        changeColumnName(table, 2, "Blahblah");
        changeColumnName(table, 3, "Blahblah Blah");
    }

    public static void changeColumnName(JTable table, int column, String name) {
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setHeaderValue(name);
    }

    public static void bindFieldToTableColumn(final JTextField field, final JTable table, final int column) {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = table.getSelectionModel();
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                onUpdate(arg0);
            }
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                onUpdate(arg0);
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                onUpdate(arg0);
            }
            public void onUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if(!table.hasFocus() && field.hasFocus()) {
                    table.setValueAt(field.getText(), table.getSelectedRow(), column);
                }
            }
        });
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                int row = e.getFirstRow();
                int col = e.getColumn();
                if(!field.hasFocus() && col == column) {
                    field.setText(table.getValueAt(row, col).toString());
                }
            }
        });
        lsm.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int selected = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(selected == -1) {
                    field.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    field.setEnabled(true);
                    Object val = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), column);
                    if(val != null) {
                        field.setText(val.toString());
                    } else {
                        field.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you matthew but that not what I really need, I think the better way is that I show you my full project at : https://github.com/MHTaleb/Encologim  try to take a look at my jtable tool at : https://github.com/MHTaleb/Encologim/tree/master/src/MyLibraries/JtableTools      to run the project is simple install wampserver and run from encologie.java , the database will be installed automatically.   I hope this helps you to understand my question or objective .